# Let $v_1,\,v_2,\,v_3,\,v_4,\,w \in \mathbb{R}^7$. If $Span(v_1,\,v_2,\,w)=Span(v_3,\,v_4,\,w)$, is it true that $Span(v_1,\,v_2)=Span( v_3,\,v_4)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to decide whether the statement is true or false, but I don't know how to proceed.
Edit 1: I changed the notation as recommended. Also, when the vectors are linearly dependent, we can take them out and reduce the case to L.I. So let's say that $ \{v_1,v_2 \}, \{ v_3,v_4 \} $ are linearly independent.

Would the answer change if we take another vector space?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am assuming that all vectors are fixed, but arbitrary, and that your notation denotes the spans of vectors. So, suggestion - try $v_2=v_4=0$ and see whether that helps you see what is going on.

Comment: In fact, try my suggestion with ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: It suffices that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent and $v_3,v_4$ are linearly independent. If you assume that all four vectors ar linearly independent the assumption is not satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought of something similar for the case when they are LD. I edited the question to consider what happens if the set of vectors is LI. (If one is, then the other also has to).

Comment: tip: use `\operatorname{span}`.

Comment: Thank you @Ryszard. It was a mistake I made with the brackets. Now they display. I don't know how to address this case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Let $v_1=e_1,$ $v_2=e_2,$ $v_3=e_1+e_3,$ $v_4=e_2+e_3$ and  $w=e_3.$ Here $e_j$ denote the elements of the standard basis. Then $$\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,w\}=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}=\operatorname{span}\{v_3,v_4,w\}$$
but
$$v_4=e_2+e_3\notin \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$$

**Remark** More generally, let $X=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n,w\}$ and $\dim X=n+1.$ Then
$$\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots v_n,w\}=\operatorname{span}\{v_1+w,v_2+w,\ldots v_n+w,w\}$$ but
$$\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\ldots v_n\}\neq \operatorname{span}\{v_1+w,v_2+w,\ldots v_n+w\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $v_1=v_2=0$, $v_3=v_4=w\ne0$.